# DAX dynamic filter using two columns from related table

Tags: ssas, powerbi, dax

I need to make some simple calculation using DAX, but I am not sure how do I achieve same result as I did in Excel's formulas. 
First of all my data structure looks as on screenshot:

[image: Matrix with data]

Measures are coming from one table, and the **PactDelivered** is an attribute from related table which is connected by relationship.

All I really have to do is to translate formula as below into DAX: 
[image]

There is no problem when it comes to calculate **B3-C3-D3**, but I have a problem how do I calculate the **- B4 + C4** part. Of course it should be dynamic, so if it comes to calculate result for Package number 10, then it'd take figures from number 10 and 11.

EDIT:

After modification of code from **Alexis Olson** I got something like below, but it's not working yet. Please note the PactDelivered is in other table than measures are. Not knowing why, but it's calculating the result on packs according to `NextPack` value. I tried adding another variable which was basically `NextPack -1`, and tried calculating the sums from return using it, but didn't work as well.

```
Cancellations:=

var NextPack = MAX('Order'[PactDelivered]) + 1

var NextOrders = CALCULATE(SUM('Fact DropOff'[OrdersSentOut]) + sum('Fact DropOff'[OrdersReturned]), 'Order'[PactDelivered] = NextPack)

return  SUM ('Fact DropOff'[OrdersSentOut]) - SUM ('Fact DropOff'[OrdersReturned] ) - SUM('Fact DropOff'[ActiveSubscriptions]) -  NextOrders
```

[image: after edits]

EDIT2:
Sample data from fact:
[image: fact]

From dimension:
[image: dimension]

Relationship:
[image: Relationship]

Comment: If you just `RETURN NextPack`, does it behave as expected?

Comment: It returns `1` in row with blank `PactDelivered`, so it seems like to be starting from blank member of this attribute.

Comment: You got the sign wrong in the `NextOrder` line. Also, you can wrap `IF(NextPack = 1, BLANK(), ...)` around your return line to remove the blank row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a measure like this:

```
Measure = 
    VAR NextPact = MAX(Orders[PactDelivered]) + 1
    VAR NextOrders = CALCULATE(SUM(Orders[OurdersSentOut]) - SUM(Orders[OrdersReturned]),
                         Orders[PactDelivered] = NextPact)
    RETURN SUM(Orders[OurdersSentOut]) - SUM(Orders[OrdersReturned]) -
           SUM(Orders[ActiveSubscriptions]) - NextOrders
```

First, we calculate the next index by taking the current index and adding 1. Then you calculate sent out minus returns for that index. Finally, subtract that from the current row calculation.

Comment: Edited my question, tried your approach with some modifications but it didn't work.

Comment: Please post your table relationship diagram and samples of what your data tables look like. It's nearly impossible to answer something like this when your structure more complex than a single table and you have not explained it well enough that someone can reproduce what you are showing.

Comment: Edited original question.